# Questions about creating 'Camera Roll'-esque functionality

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am fairly new to Objective-C so forgive my ignorance ahead of time =] Here is what I have so far:

- The application is a tab bar style application
- The view, as relevant to this post, contains several buttons that when clicked pull down different types of images
- On click of the button an Array is populated with the data returned from the web service
- A new view is displayed with a UIImageView inside of it

Now here is what I am hoping to get clarification on (or simply ideas)

- As I said the application itself is a tab bar style app but I am having some trouble with the third view I've added.  Currently when I click on a button the view loads correctly but it is loading inside of the Tab Bar view area.  This isn't optimal and I would like for this new view to be displayed overtop of the Tab Bar thus taking up the entire area on the phone. I am opening this view from inside the View Controller that contains the button (which is a tab view) like this:

  `UIViewController * browsePictures = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PictureGalleryViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [self.view addSubview:browsePictures.view];`
- On this third view I have a UIImageView (I am not sure this is the correct view for the app) that needs to be populated via the data that is returned from the web service.  Returning binary data, as I found out, is very inefficient via JSON so I am returning URL's which means I will need to make a call out to the web for every image returned.  I am ok with this I am just curious if there is a better way to do it.
- The functionality I am trying to achieve with this third view is similar to the Camera Roll functionality of the iPhone.  In this case when the user gestures to the left or the right it would move the current index of the array up or down one and load the next photo in the array.  I am not sure how to implement this functionality.

I think that is all for now.  Thanks!